# Migrate from Hibernate 4 to 5

Tags: java, hibernate

I have some problems with migration from hibernate 4.3 to hibernate 5.
I'm working on a major project where we use SequenceHiLoGenerator to generate id which is deprecated now. How update this without major changes?

This is my code with hibernate 4.3.

```
public class KSequenceGenerator extends SequenceHiLoGenerator {
@Override
public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
    Serializable id = session.getEntityPersister(null, object).getClassMetadata().getIdentifier(object, session);
    return id != null ? id : super.generate(session, object);
}
```

In EJB:

```
@GenericGenerator(name="id_gen", strategy="com.or.nk.ob.base.KSequenceGenerator", parameters = {@org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = KSequenceGenerator.SEQUENCE, value = "building_id_seq")})
```

now i have:

```
public class KSequenceGenerator extends SequenceStyleGenerator { 
public static final String SEQUENCE = "sequence";

@Override public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException { 
    Serializable id = session.getEntityPersister(null, object).getClassMetadata().getIdentifier(object, session); 
    return id != null ? id : super.generate(session, object); 
}
```

}

id:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "id_gen", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Comment: Did you have a look at `SequenceStyleGenerator` which is suggested to be used instead?

Comment: so i can do like this?

Comment: `public class KSequenceGenerator extends SequenceStyleGenerator {
    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
        Serializable id = session.getEntityPersister(null, object).getClassMetadata().getIdentifier(object, session);
        return id != null ? id : super.generate(session, object);
    }
}`

Comment: Just try it. Btw, please don't put that much code into a comment but rather [edit] your question instead.

Comment: it works! Thanks :)

Comment: now i have another problem, this generator give me wrong id, sometimes index exists in table and hibernate give me ORA-00001 error... question updated